# System of modular equations with solutions in an interval

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, congruences, integer-programming

How can I find $x$ in this system of arithmetic constraints?

$$\begin{align}
523688865268425016 < & x < 732502104004147816 \\
& x \equiv 13135 \pmod {249853} \\
& x \equiv 447151 \pmod {598363} \\
& x \equiv 539404 \pmod {698359}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Maybe [chinese remainer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)?